# stuck if the middle of applying method of characteristics for this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

solve for $u(x,y)$. when $$-yu_x+xu_y=u$$ $$u(x,0)=\psi(x)$$
This is what I did:
$$\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{u}$$
Now from $\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}$, I get $C_1=x^2+y^2$.

 and from $\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{du}{u}$, I get $C_2=u.e^{\frac{x}{y}}$
$$C_2=f(C_1)$$
$$u.e^{\frac{x}{y}}=x^2+y^2$$
$$u=e^{\frac{-x}{y}}.f(x^2+y^2)$$
since $u(x,0)=\psi(x)$ then 
$$\psi(x)=e^{-x}{0}.f(x^2)$$
Now I am stuck, it does not look good at all!
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: $C_2=u.e^{x/y}$ is false.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was that you treated $y$ as a constant when you were integrating, so the exponential is false. See this question: [Find the solution of the pde $xu_y-yu_x=u$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080115/find-the-solution-of-the-pde-xu-y-yu-x-u?rq=1).

This gives the general form of the solution as
\begin{equation}
u(x,y)=\exp\left(\pm \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y} \right) \right)F(x^2+y^2)
\end{equation}

You may then plug in the boundary condition.

Comment: very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{u}$$
First integral curve:
$$\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}$$
$$\implies x^2+y^2=C_1$$
For the second integral curve, we have: 
$$\frac{dx}{-y}=\frac{dy}{x}=\frac{du}{u}$$
$$\frac{ydx}{-y^2}=\frac{xdy}{x^2}=\frac{du}{u}$$
$$\frac{ydx-xdy}{-y^2-x^2}=\frac{du}{u}$$
$$\frac{xdy-ydx}{y^2+x^2}=\frac{du}{u}$$
$$d\arctan \frac y x=\frac{du}{u}$$
$$\arctan \frac y x=\ln u +c_2$$
$$\implies u(x,y)=C_2\exp \{\arctan \frac y x\}$$
Therefore 
$$C_2=F(C_1)$$
$$\ln u=\arctan \frac y x +F(x^2+y^2)$$
$$\boxed {u(x,y)=F(x^2+y^2)\exp  \left \{\arctan \frac y x \right \} }$$

Apply initial condition.